# How to exclude generated code from coverage statistics

Tags: testing, go

I have thrift generated code in my project? How do I stop this from affecting my coverage stats? They're dismal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This help message from `go test` seems to suggest you can filter the packages you're testing:

```
-coverpkg pkg1,pkg2,pkg3
    Apply coverage analysis in each test to the given list of packages.
    The default is for each test to analyze only the package being tested.
    Packages are specified as import paths.
    Sets -cover.
```

Another simpler option, and this is what I do, is to import the generated code as a library package that sits outside your code tree, and thus the cover tool ignores it in its stats.

e.g. if your app is `github.com/Fuser97381/myproj`, put the generated code in `github.com/Fuser97381/protocols`. Then your code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
      "github.com/Fuser97381/protocols/myproto"
      "git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift"
)

...
```

Comment: That works for packages, but not generated code within the same project. I like your avatar, Dude!

Comment: @Fuser97381 can't you put the generated code somewhere else? What I do is simple: I put the generated code in a separate project, that includes only thrift gen stuff (this also helps by making generation a build job), and is imported with go get. Then the coverage of my app does not include the metrics for this library. The Dude Abides!

Comment: @Fuser97381 I'm assuming the "selected" is because of my comment? If so, I'll modify my answer to describe this pattern in greater detail for future generations.

Comment: That would really tie this question together. It takes an answerer like you to get through to the asker in me. You're answering easy for all us sinners.